# App with news fromw website reader (rss, json) and displaying them users (notifications, storing)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, push-notification, rss, ionic2

I need to create a provider in my #ionic-2 app with RSS reader functionality.

I have some website with RSS feed (XML format) but I can return data in JSON format as well.

Now I'm thinking which concept is the best to create mobile app with news from this website.

Below are some ideas but I don't know whether they are possible to create.

**Reading news**

a) when user opens app then app reads the news from website

b) using Push notifications:

- create nodejs / express app which checks the news on website and using some platform (1) sends notifications about last added news
- using cron and PHP script checks the news in database (MySQL) and using some platform (1) sends notifications about last added news
- maybe is there other solution?

*(1) - some platform - I don't know which and how - maybe someone have good experience with any?

**Storing news**

a) news should be store in database (PouchDB)?

b) if yes, they should be removed after some period of time?

c) if no, is it efficient to get news from website every time when app opens?

d) maybe is there other solution?

This app will be run on iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

If someone can help me with some of these issues I would be grateful :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All those ideas are implementable.
b) using Push notifications: [Create an Azure Mobile app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKWEXU8i5oc). Go through the videos until part 7 and the final one which will be uploaded tonight or tomorrow.
For everything else you asked, start writing code first. As I said, they are all implementable. How ? There is no single answer for that in my view.